# Make Lookup columns read only in a list view

Tags: list

I have a list with an all items view and it has a couple of lookup columns in it. I want to make those columns read only instead of being hyperlinks. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On option would be to add custom JavaScript that "unwraps" the text from the Anchor tag.
The following example accomplishes a more complicated scenario, but the general idea can be used to add the custom JS to achieve your goal.

http://blog.vgrem.com/2012/12/09/customize-the-rendering-of-a-view-in-list-view-in-sharepoint-2010-displaying-list-items-arranged-in-accordion/

jQuery unwrap: http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/